# Settings $_ in a script block invocation

Tags: powershell

In a complex script, I have a bunch a calls that repeat the same pattern: **prepare,execute,clean**.

Only the **execute** part is different, so I want to define only once the **prepare** and **clean** calls.

To achieve this, I'd like to wrap this in a function, having the **execute** part passed as a parameter.

I tried this:

```
function SomeFunc{
    param(
        [scriptblock]$Action,
        [int]$x,
        [int]$y
    )


    Write-Host "Before"

    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $Action  -PipelineVariable ($x*$y) 

    Write-Host "After"

}


SomeFunc  -x 2 -y 4 -Action {  Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Result is $_"  }
```

But this not works. `$_` is always empty.

How can I reach my goal?

Comment: What are you doing with `-PipelineVariable` there? Doesn't it take the name of the variable to assign the pipeline variable to? Do you want to pass that result as an *argument* to the invoked block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass arguments for the ScriptBlock not through the pipeline but as arguments in array as `ArgumentList` parameter to the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet. Then you will be able to access the arguments by $args variable inside your 'process' ScriptBlock.

```
function SomeFunc {
    param ($x, $y, $sb)
    Write-Host "Before";
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList @("Some string", $x, ($x * $y))
    Write-Host "After";
}
SomeFunc -x 4 -y 2 -sb { foreach ($a in $args) { Write-Host ("Parameter: $a")  } }
```

The output would be

```
Before
Parameter: Some string
Parameter: 4
Parameter: 8
After
```

You can also include `param()` block inside your ScriptBlock. This way allows you to easily place additional restrictions on the arguments, such as strong typing

```
function SomeFunc {
    param ($x, $y, $sb)
    Write-Host "Before";
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList @("Not x", $y, ($x * $y));
    Write-Host "After";
}
SomeFunc -x 4 -y 2 -sb { param ([int]$a, $b, $c) Write-Host ("a is {0}, c is {1}, b is {2}" -f $a, $c, $b)}
```

The output shows the error

```
Before
Invoke-Command : Cannot convert value "Not x" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At line:4 char:5
+     Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList @("Not x", $y, ($x * $y));
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], PSInvalidCastException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand

After
```

Comment: using the `param` within my script block is what I was looking for. Thx

Comment: You are welcome. In reality all functions and scripts are just scriptblocks. If you enter `$function:SomeFunc` you'll see the body of the function - which is a script block. Basically it means that things you can do with functions and scripts can be done with scriptblocks either, e.g. including `param`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really need to pipeline to it, you can just use a variable that is set:

```
function SomeFunc{
    param(
        [scriptblock]$Action,
        [int]$x,
        [int]$y
    )

    $s = $x*$y
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $Action

}

[scriptblock]$sb = { Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Result is $s" }
SomeFunc  -x 2 -y 4 -Action $sb
```